# Не могу изменить часовой пояс php

Tags: php, apache, дата, timezone

Не могу понять откуда берется часовой пояс.
В php.ini указано:
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/Moscow

Непосредственно в скрипте:
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

Выполнение вот такого кода:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Moscow');
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s Z e P T') . "</br>";
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s Z e P T');
```

выдает вот такой результат

```
28.03.2017 00:16:14 3600 Europe/London +01:00 BST
27.03.2017 23:16:14 0 GMT +00:00 GMT
```

при этом время на лаптопе

```
date
Вт. марта 28 02:17:54 MSK 2017
```

Скрипт работает локально.

Comment: вывод `phpinfo()` в особености `Loaded Configuration File ` предоставьте в вопросе

Comment: Вывод всего phpinfo?
Virtual Directory Support  disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d

date
date/time support  enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version  0.system
Timezone Database  internal
Default timezone  Europe/Moscow